# Xunit and MOQ: How to moq a generic function which returns a list

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

I'm using .net 3.1 core, MOQ and Xunit. Working with uow and repository.
I have a function in a generic repository(see below). How can i moq `Getitems` to return a List?

Method in generic Repo:

```
public async Task<List<TType>> GetItems<TType>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy, Expression<Func<T, TType>> select) where TType : class
{
    var Query = await _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).Select(select).ToListAsync();
    return Query;
}
```

I tried this:

```
_artikelAfwijkingen = new List<ArtAfwijking>()
{
    new ArtAfwijking { Kd_Artikel = "Artikel_1", Kd_Instantie = "ACHM", LicNumber = 80, Nr_Filiaal = 0},
    new ArtAfwijking { Kd_Artikel = "Artikel_1", Kd_Instantie = "ACHM", LicNumber = 0, Nr_Filiaal = 0},
    new ArtAfwijking { Kd_Artikel = "Artikel_1", Kd_Instantie = "ACHM", LicNumber = 100, Nr_Filiaal = 0}
};
        
artAfwijkingRepository.CallBase = true;
artAfwijkingRepository.Setup(m => m.GetItems<ArtAfwijking>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ArtAfwijking, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ArtAfwijking, object>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ArtAfwijking, ArtAfwijking>>>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(_artikelAfwijkingen));;

var repository = artAfwijkingRepository.Object;
var artAfwijk = await repository.GetArtAfwijkingAsync("ARTIKEL_X", "ACHM", 80, 0, false);
```

Method of ArtAfwijkingRepository file:

```
public async Task<ArtAfwijking> GetArtAfwijkingAsync(string artikelCode, string instantieCode, int licentieNummer, short? filiaalNummer, bool overnemenOmschrijving)
{
    List<ArtAfwijking> artikelAfwijkingen = await GetItems(a => a.Kd_Artikel == artikelCode && a.Kd_Instantie == instantieCode && a.Nr_Filiaal == filiaalNummer, a => a.Kd_Artikel, a => a);
    if (artikelAfwijkingen.Count == 1)
        return (artikelAfwijkingen[0]);
    return null
}
```

Comment: What have you tired? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have updated my Question. The code would'nt compile because of .ReturnsAsync<_artikelAfwijkingen>)

Comment: Try to change `.ReturnsAsync(_artikelAfwijkingen)` to `.ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult(_artikelAfwijkingen))`

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, .ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult(_artikelAfwijkingen)) did not work. I changed it to .Returns(Task.FromResult(_artikelAfwijkingen)) and this compiles. But my problem is that when debugging it doesn't enters the method(GetArtAfwijkingAsync) in de repo

Comment: If you are mocking the `IArtAfwijkingRepository` then that impacts `GetItems` and `GetArtAfwijkingAsync` as well. If you want to keep the original functionality of `GetArtAfwijkingAsync` then you shoud set the following: `artAfwijkingRepository.CallBase = true;` before the `Setup` call.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, I have added artAfwijkingRepository.CallBase = true before the setup call. But the code doesn't enter method(GetArtAfwijkingAsync) in de repo. BTW, GetItems is a method in the generic repo.